# Потеря контекста при передачи в другую функцию

Tags: javascript

Есть класс консруктор с несколькими методами.

```
class AlarmClock {
  constructor() {
    this.alarmCollection = [];
  } 

addClock(time, func, id) {
        let item = { id: id, time: time, callback: func };
        this.alarmCollection.push(item);
        console.log("Будильник взведен");
  }

  start() {
    let timerId = () => setInterval(this.checkClock(), 0); //неправильная передача данных
    this.alarmCollection.forEach(function (item) {
      console.table(item);
      timerId(item, 0);
    });
  }

  checkClock(item) {
    let data = "09:01";
    console.log(item);
    if (data == item.time) {
      item.callback();
    }
    return "Вызов успешный";
  }

}
```

Создаем новый объект и запускаем несколько методов

```
let phoneAlarm = new AlarmClock();
phoneAlarm.addClock("09:00", () => console.log("Пора вставать"), 1);
phoneAlarm.addClock("09:01", () => console.log("Давай, вставай уже!"), 2);
phoneAlarm.start();
```

Проблема заключается в потере конкекста при вызове метода checkClock из start. Пробовал с call как-то это решить, но так и не смог.

Comment: Решение для Вас https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749244/javascript-setinterval-and-this-solution

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю, то вот это вот `let timerId = () => setInterval(this.checkClock(), 0)` положит в timerId не функцию, а номер интервала и даже если вы дальше пройдете по коду, то получите сообщение, что timerid не функция. Что бы убедиться, замените эту строчку вот так `let timerId = setInterval(this.checkClock(), 0)`

Comment: @SwaD, _то получите сообщение, что timerid не функция_ - но она же у него функция.

Comment: @Grundy да, действительно. Видимо в образе был...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только зачем в timerId присваивать функцию? Название переменной странное.

```
start() {
    let timerId = (_item, timer) => setInterval(()=>this.checkClock(_item), timer);  
    this.alarmCollection.forEach(function (item) {
      console.table(item);
      timerId(item, 2000);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так надо:

```
class AlarmClock {
  constructor() {
    this.alarmCollection = [];
  } 

  addClock(time, func, id) {
        let item = { id: id, time: time, callback: func };
        this.alarmCollection.push(item);
        console.log("Будильник взведен");
  }

  start() {
    this.alarmCollection.forEach(
    (item) => {
      console.table(item);
      setInterval(() => this.checkClock(item), 1000);
    });
  }

  checkClock(item) {
    console.log("checkClock",item);
    item.callback();
  }
} 

let phoneAlarm = new AlarmClock();
phoneAlarm.addClock("09:00", ()=> console.log("Пора вставать"), 1);
phoneAlarm.addClock("09:01", ()=> console.log("Давай, вставай уже!"), 2);
phoneAlarm.start();
```